# Discerning between files and folders on a shared drive under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, directory, dirent.h

I am trying to list all the files in a certain directory on a shared drive using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "dirent.h"

int main ()
{
    DIR *directoryHandle = opendir("./temp/");
    if (NULL != directoryHandle)
    {
        dirent *entry = readdir(directoryHandle);
        while (NULL != entry)
        {
            //skip directories and select only files (hopefully)
            if ((DT_DIR != entry->d_type) && (DT_REG == entry->d_type || DT_UNKNOWN == entry->d_type))
            {
                std::cout << "Name: " << entry->d_name << " Type:" << std::to_string(entry->d_type) << std::endl;
            }

            //go to next entry
            entry = readdir(directoryHandle);
        }
        closedir(directoryHandle);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that entry->d_type contains DT_UNKNOWN for directories as well as for files in the `./temp/` directory.

Is there any (reliable) linux-specific way to try and read each entry and determine if it's a file or directory?

The output of `cat /etc/SuSE-release` is:

> SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 (x86_64) VERSION = 11 PATCHLEVEL = 1

The Linux version is: 2.6.32.59-0.7-default

Still, I expect this code to work on other platforms as well.

Comment: What does "shared drive" mean here? smb,nfs, sshfs etc.? oh and you are confusing the kernel version with the distro version.

Comment: Ups... I'm not that experienced with the Linux system. The output of `df -T` indicates `nfs4` for that drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stat`. You'll get a `struct stat` with an `st_mode` field, and macros `S_ISDIR`/`S_ISREG`:

```
isDirectory = S_ISDIR(statBuf.st_mode);
isFile = S_ISREG(statBuf.st_mode);
```

See `man 2 stat`. Include `sys/stat.h`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting `DT_UNKNOWN` you're going to have to go ahead and call [`lstat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) and inspect the `st_mode` field to determine if this is a file, directory, or symlink. If you don't care about symlinks, use `stat()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) that has a command [is_directory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_directory).
Using such a library would certainly make the code work on other platforms as well but I'm not sure if it will work for your specific problem.

Comment: I prefer not to create a dependency on boost::filesystem at this point...

Comment: +1 for Boost::FS, it's a great library and much easier to use than `dirent.h`.

Comment: @MihaiTodor Well that's a design choice and it's your design so that's that. I think I'm sometimes a bit trigger happy when including boost libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. It list files in a directory minus the folders :

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/mode.h>
# include <stat.h>

DIR           *d;
struct dirent *dir;
struct stat s;
d = opendir("./temp/");

if (d)
{
  while ((dir = readdir(d)))
  {
    if (stat(dir->d_name,&s) != 0) {
        /* is this a regular file? */
        if ((s.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFREG)
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);

    }
  }
  closedir(d);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
unsigned char isFolder =0x4;
DIR Dir;
struct dirent *DirEntry;
Dir = opendir("c:/test/")

while(Dir=readdir(Dir))
{
    cout << DirEntry->d_name;
    if ( DirEntry->d_type == isFolder)
    {
    cout <<"Found a Directory : " << DirEntry->d_name << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: So, how's this different from my code? DT_DIR is defined as 0x4...